# Pass environment variables as input to Docker entrypoint

Tags: python, docker, arguments

Suppose I have

`ENTRYPOINT ["python", "myscript.py"]`

and `myscript.py` has an argument `--envvar`

That is, if I were to run it locally, I would run `python myscript --envvar $envvar`

Is there any way to provide this argument in Docker, given that I've already chosen to make Python my entrypoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s really an environment variable, use the `docker run -e` option.

```
docker run -e VAR=value myimage
```

Alternately, anything you specify as a “command”, either things after the image name in the `docker run` command or a Dockerfile CMD directive, get passed as command-line arguments to the entrypoint.

```sh
# note: your local shell expands $envvar
docker run myimage --envvar "$envvar"
```